# How to mask sensitive properties in log files c#.net?

Tags: c#, json, security, logging, privacy

I am using the Logentries tool to file logs in my asp.net web api application.
It will log all request and response bodies.
I will have some sensitive fields like passwords and identification numbers. I have to mask them in logs.
I have to do this in a common method, where all the request or response will be passed to that method before logging and it will mask the specified properties.
How can I do this?

Comment: which thitd party tool are you using. and which method u use for logging

Comment: Please add the tool you are using. Further, you should not be passing passwords in requests and responses, I suggest you revisit your authentication design too. On the logging, aim to write a pre-processor between the log tool and your code that looks for sensitive information and masks it, for example, replace a social security number with ##########

Comment: Seriously, how are we supposed to know which tool you use and which technology your tool uses for logging? Why don't you just contact your "3rd party tool provider" for support?

Comment: Can you suggest me whether there are any open source code available for implementing pre-processor?

Comment: Also worth mentioning is that you should hash and even better, hash and salt your passwords so that even if the sensitive password field is not "masked", then the information will be more or less useless to an intruder.